# Query to get identifier and aggregate function value of a row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

Having the following two tables in a MySQL Database:

```
USER
 - ID
 - Name

GAME1
 - ID
 - UserID
 - Score
 - Rank
```

This is what I need in a view:

```
 - User.ID
 - User.Name
 - Game1.ID as MaxScoreGameID
 - Max(Game1.Score) as MaxScore
 - Game1.ID as BestRankGameID
 - Min(Game1.Rank) as BestRank
```

I got it working without GameIDs, but I also need the IDs of the games where `MaxScore` and `BestRank` occurred.

I searched the web for some information and tried `GROUP_CONCAT`, `HAVING`, ... but I could not get the results I need.

**edit**

As a result of the query I except one row per user with the `MaxScore` and `BestRank` and the IDs of the games where these were reached.
If a User has the same score (which is best) in more than 1 game, I only want one of these in the user row.

Comment: added expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.ID
     , u.Name
     , (SELECT sub.ID from Game1 as sub where sub.UserID = u.ID ORDER BY sub.Score desc LIMIT 1) as MaxScoreGameID
     , Max(Game1.Score) as MaxScore
     , (SELECT sub2.ID from Game1 as sub2 where sub2.UserID = u.ID ORDER BY Rank asc LIMIT 1) as BestRankGameID
     , Min(Game1.Rank) as BestRank
FROM [User] u
JOIN Game1 on Game1.UserID = u.ID GROUP BY u.ID, u.Name
```

The idea is to use Subselects to find the max score and use that score to get the Game1.ID. Same idea is used for Game1.Rank.

Comment: `where Rank = Min(Game1.Rank)` isn't right, you can't mix plain values and aggregates that way.  You're probaly looking for an `order by Score desc limit 1` subquery.

Comment: Your main query is mixing aggregated and non-aggregated results and yet it doesn't have a GROUP BY. It just won't return the desired results this way.

Comment: @Andomar Fixed the subselect.

Comment: @AndriyM Added Group By. You are right, I totally forgot to add it in my original post. Shame on me. :(

Comment: The edited version works good and I will only get one row per user, even if the user had the same best score in two games.

Comment: Sorry but you forgot one thing: (SELECT Game1.ID from Game1 where Score = (SELECT TOP 1 sub.Score from Game1 as sub ORDER BY Score desc)) gives the best score over all users and not per user.

Comment: @TheCutter: I added a `where sub.UserID = User.ID` to the subselect in question.

Comment: SELECT u.ID
     , u.Name
     , (SELECT TOP 1 sub.ID from Game1 as sub where sub.UserID = u.ID ORDER BY sub.Score desc) as MaxScoreGameID
     , Max(Game1.Score) as MaxScore
     , (SELECT TOP 1 sub2.ID from Game1 as sub2 where sub2.UserID = u.ID ORDER BY Rank asc) as BestRankGameID
     , Min(Game1.Rank) as BestRank
FROM [User] u
     JOIN Game1 on Game1.UserID = u.ID
GROUP BY u.ID, u.Name
This works now! Please edit your answer accordingly, so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: One last thing to note: For MySQL it should be LIMIT 1 at the end of the subquery and not TOP 1. =)

Comment: @TheCutter: Thanks. Seems like every SQL derivative is trying to implement it's own keyword. For FirebirdSQL it's "first 1" for example. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filtering join.  The example is just for score, but you can add a second filtering join for rank.

```
select  u.name
,       g1.ID as MaxScoreGameID
,       g1.Score as MaxScore
from    User u
join    (
        select  UserID
        ,       max(Score) as maxScore
        from    Game1
        group by
                UserID
        ) as MaxScorePerUser
on      MaxScorePerUser.UserID = u.ID
join    Game1 g1
on      u.ID = g1.UserID
        and MaxScorePerUser.MaxScore = g1.Score
```

Comment: This works good, but if a user had the same best score in two games I will get two rows. Forgott to mention it in my question, that this could happen.

Comment: @TheCutter: And you forgot to mention (even now) what the result should look like in that case.

Comment: Added this case to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id, u.name, g1.Score as MaxScore, g2.Rank as BestRank,
from user u
left outer join
 (select  g11. UserID, max(g11.Score) as Score from GAME1 as g11 group by  g12.UserID 
 ) g1 on u.id=g1.UserID
 left outer join
 (select  g12.UserID, max(g12.Rank) as Rank  from GAME1 as g12 group by  g12.UserID 
 ) g2 on u.id=g2.UserID
```

or

```
select u.id, u.name, g3.id, g1.Score as MaxScore, g3.id, g2.Rank as BestRank,
from user u
left outer join
 (select  g11. UserID, max(g11.Score) as Score from GAME1 as g11 group by  g12.UserID 
 ) g1 on u.id=g1.UserID
 left outer join
 (select  g12.UserID, max(g12.Rank) as Rank  from GAME1 as g12 group by  g12.UserID 
 ) g2 on u.id=g2.UserID
 left outer join GAME1 g3 on (g1.Score=g3.Score or g2.Rank=g3.Rank) and u.id=g3.UserID
```

or

```
  select u.id, u.name, g3.id, g1.Score as MaxScore, g4.id, g2.Rank as BestRank,
    from user u
    left outer join
     (select  g11. UserID, max(g11.Score) as Score from GAME1 as g11 group by  g12.UserID 
     ) g1 on u.id=g1.UserID
     left outer join
     (select  g12.UserID, max(g12.Rank) as Rank  from GAME1 as g12 group by  g12.UserID 
     ) g2 on u.id=g2.UserID
     left outer join GAME1 g3 on g1.Score=g3.Score and u.id=g3.UserID
      left outer join GAME1 g4 on  g2.Rank=g4.Rank and u.id=g4.UserID
```

Comment: `having g11.Score=max(g11.Score)`: You can't mix aggregates with plain values.  A group has a maximum score, but it doesn't have a plain score.

Comment: Thinking in sets can be tough!  Try your answer on www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Thanks, but that does not give me the needed results, because the game id for MaxScore and BestRank can be different.

Comment: let's try with third query is may be fine for you?

Comment: Sry but this does not work as expected and it does not seem to be a clear and easy statement with so many joins. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by a example that doesnt solve your whole need. If you want the MaxScore for each user in each game the query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    User.ID,
    User.Name,
    Game1.ID as MaxScoreGameID,
    Max(Game1.Score) as MaxScore,
FROM
    User
JOIN
    Game1
ON
    Game1.UserID = User.ID
GROUP BY
    User.ID, User.Name, Game1.ID
```

The standard `JOIN` and the `GROUP BY` needs to list all the parameters that should be respected by the aggregation. (From a business logic point of view it should only list User.ID and Game1.ID, since User.Name is dependent from User.ID, but that is a technical detail and you would probably not want to redesign your database because of that.)

You could rewrite the statement above to retrieve `Min(Game1.Rank) as BestRank` instead. Now the question remains on how to extend that query to list both values at the same time.

You have to decide if that can be done in the same join (meaning that the highest score always is the best rank too) or if a seperate join is required (meaning that some other score than MaxScoreGameID could have the BestRank - maybe in a game you are trying to get close to 0 points?).

IF two separate joins are required, you have to join `Game1` twice.

```
SELECT 
    User.ID,
    User.Name,
    g1max.ID as MaxScoreGameID,
    Max(g1max.Score) as MaxScore,
    g1min.ID as BestRankGameID,
    Min(g1min.Rank) as BestRank,
FROM
    User
JOIN
    Game1 g1max
ON
    g1max.UserID = User.ID
JOIN
    Game1 g1min
ON
    g1min.UserID = User.ID
GROUP BY
    User.ID, User.Name, g1max.ID, g1min.ID
```

Comment: If you group on a primary key like `ID`, all you do is create groups containing one row.  Thus your query will return all scores, not just the maximum ones.

Comment: That is just wrong. `GROUP BY User.ID` makes sure we get one row for each `User.ID`. If we remove that we would get the maximum score of *all players*.

Comment: This gives the result Andomar said. Because of the GROUP BY on User.ID I get back a long list...

Comment: Of course it returnes a long list. Your question does not show that you do NOT want a long list. I recommend you add a description of the desired result in a complete sentence. My statement will return `the highest score and lowest rank that any player has in any game`, so naturally that list has the dimension `|players| * |games|`

Comment: Ok sorry I thought that would be clear from my question.

Comment: Its getting clearer now. But do you really want to compare the scores across several games? I would expect that in one game 1337 is a good score and in a different game 123456789 is a good score. Since there are other working answers for your question already I will not elaborate on the new situation =)

Comment: No every Game has its own Table, because they have different goals to achieve. Score/Rank, Kills/Deaths, ...